# how to order by and group by equal column values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is:

```
   device_name | device_category
---------------------------------
standard_spot  |    light
mobile_spot    |    light
tracker        |    light
smoking_machine|    light
microphone1    |    sound
microphone2    |    sound
display1_hmdi  |    projector
display1_vga   |    projector
display1_sound |    projector
```

I need a query that provides the `device_names` together with the `device_categories` ordered by the occurrence of a `device_category`.
My attempt was this query, which provides the occurrences of each category:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_dcats FROM `devices` GROUP BY device_category ORDER BY num_dcats DESC
```

Like this:

```
device_category | num_dcats
---------------------------
light           |  4
projector       |  3
sound           |  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select d.*
from devices d
join (
  select device_category, count(*) as cnt from devices group by device_category
) c on c.device_category = d.device_category
order by c.cnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select d.*, count(*) over (partition by device_category) as num_cats
from devices d
order by num_cats;
```

Comment: This answer did it almost, but the output order was: lowest occurrence, highest occurrence, mid occurrence from bottom to top of the table, but thank you!

Comment: @redmir . . . If you care about the order in the result set (which I missed in your question), you need an `order by`.